# How to get clicked layout items in listactivity?

Tags: java, android, textview, listactivity

I have a layout which has two `TextView`s and an `ArrayList` to fill those `TextView`s. I just want to open a new child activity when an item is clicked to show detailed view about this item. But I couldn't find a way to do that. Here is my part of code :

```
String[] columns = new String[] { "name", "distance" };
int[] renderTo = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.distance}; 

ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, 
        R.layout.textview_list, columns, renderTo);
setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExpandableListView` will be the most suitable thing in this scenario.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) out.

Answer (score 0):

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()

{

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id)
     {


        // Call the new activity here   



 }
```

});